# How to test if a specific page is the front page?

Tags: menus, navigation, frontpage

How do I determine of a specific post id belongs to a page that is set as the front page (set as static front page via settings > readings in the backend)?

Context:
I want to write a function, that returns all menu children of a specific page and menu:

```
function getMenuChildren($menuId, $postId)
{
    $menuItems = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menuId);
    if (is_front_page()) {
        $menuIdOfCurrentPage = 0;
    } else {
        foreach ($menuItems as $menuItem) {
            if ((int) $menuItem->object_id === $postId) {
                $menuIdOfCurrentPage = $menuItem->ID;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    $childrenMenuItems = [];
    if (isset($menuIdOfCurrentPage)) {
        foreach ($menuItems as $menuItem) {
            if ((int) $menuItem->menu_item_parent === $menuIdOfCurrentPage)
                $childrenMenuItems[] = $menuItem;
        }
    }
    return $childrenMenuItems;
}
```

I use that only for the current page, so the code above works, but of course the `is_front_page()` is not the way, I want to write a function. Renaming the function to `getMenuChildrenOfCurrentPost` and remove the `$postId` parameter would be wordpress style, of course, but thats also not the way, I want to write code.

**Update**

Here is the result after the answer from "birgire":

```
function getMenuChildren($menuId, $postId)
{
    $menuItems = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menuId);
    if ($postId === (int) get_option('page_on_front')) {
        $menuIdOfPage = 0;
    } else {
        foreach ($menuItems as $menuItem) {
            if ((int) $menuItem->object_id === $postId) {
                $menuIdOfPage = $menuItem->ID;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    $childrenMenuItems = [];
    if (isset($menuIdOfPage)) {
        foreach ($menuItems as $menuItem) {
            if ((int) $menuItem->menu_item_parent === $menuIdOfPage)
                $childrenMenuItems[] = $menuItem;
        }
    }
    return $childrenMenuItems;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to replace:

```
if (is_front_page()) {
    $menuIdOfCurrentPage = 0;
```

with a check for the `page_on_front` option:

```
if( 
       is_int( $postID ) 
    && $postID > 0 
    && $postID === (int) get_option( 'page_on_front' ) 
) {
    $menuIdOfCurrentPage = 0;
```

Here we added a check to see if  `$postID` is a positive integer, because the `page_on_front` option is 0 if no page is selected as a frontpage.

Then consider renaming `$menuIdOfCurrentPage`  to `$menuIdOfPage`.

In PHP 7, we could for example use [strict scalar type declerations](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration):

```
function getMenuChildren( int $menuId, int $postId )
{
```

where it would throw a TypeError when used with non integer input arguments:

> Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   getMenuChildren() must be of the type integer, none given, called in
>   [...][...] on line 10 and defined in [...][...]

using `declare( strict_types = 1 );`.

Comment: Thank you a lot. It works. Also thank you for the hint to rename the variable. I forgot to rename it after moving the code from the header template into a function.

Comment: you're welcome. you might also want to check if `$postID` is > 0, because the `page_on_front` option is stored as 0 when no page is selected as frontpage  @stofl

Comment: In what case could a post id be 0? wp_posts.ID has the AUTO_INCREMENT flag and should always start with 1.

I removed the (int) before $postId, because I'm passing the value as integer (but maybe $post->ID is not always an integer?)

Comment: In general we shouldn't trust the input arguments. For example another developer (or ourselves in few months time, when we've forgotten about the  details) could just call `getMenuChildren( 0, 0 )` or just `getMenuChildren()`. Maybe in some edge cases the input might not be an integer, e.g. if the user is using some undefined variables as input argument ;-) So there are various scenarios possible to break it;-) @stofl

Comment: My point of view is different: We cannot trust input from outside of the system. But we have to trust the input from code within the system. We cannot write every single function to be bullet proof against wrong usage by other developers - that would be nice, but it's to much work. Of course if we write apis of libraries, we should throw errors, if the user passes invalid values, but this function is not meant to be an api to be used in other contexts.

Comment: thanks for sharing your view, there are many views on this for sure,  just use what makes the most sense for your work ;-) @stofl

Comment: Is this supposed to work with localized content using Polylang?

Comment: Best to ask Polylang's developers @IngoSteinke

Comment: @birgire Polylang has a method to get the frontpage in the current active language, so we can imply `current_page_on_front_id = pll_get_post( get_option('page_on_front') )`

Comment: Thanks for sharing that info @IngoSteinke